# How to Integrate TortoiseSVN and Jenkins?

Tags: svn, jenkins, tortoisesvn

I'm building a little prototype on my Windows machine. I've got Jenkins running, and am using TortoiseSVN as my repo, the location of which is at: file:///C:/SVNRepo

When I try to add that as the repository URL in Jenkins I get the following error:

```
Unable to access file:///C:/SVNRepo : svn: E180001: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
svn: E180001: Unable to open repository 'file:///C:/SVNRepo'
```

Strangely enough that repository location works in Subclipse though. What am I missing to use  TortoiseSVN with Jenkins?

Comment: For the record, TortoiseSVN is a windows SVN client, not an SVN server/repo

Comment: Which version are you using? I can configure a subversion repository using `file:///E:/myRepo` and works. Perhaps is it a permissions problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, did some more digging and figured it out myself. I enabled command-line through TortoiseSVN, set up svnserve.exe as a service on my windows machine, ran the service, and then used the svn:// protocol as the URL for the Jenkins build. Now everything is working.

Comment: Hey, this post is old, but I will try.... I have the same problem. Can you explaine your solution with more details

Answer (score -1):

You need to install visual svn server; offering "https://" url to access local repository... refer to the video 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yGIo9_x-YSo

Comment: Installing visual svn server will allow repository management and access over http:// but this doesn't answer the question of how to get jenkins integration using file:// access