# Jenkins + TortoiseSVN - Can't connect/integrate

Tags: unit-testing, svn, jenkins, tortoisesvn, hudson

I can't connect Jenkins with TortoiseSVN. I try to connect my Jenkins with my local tortoise, so have no online server.

I used `file:///C:/Users/a.simon/SVN/MyRepository` to access my local repository, but it doesn't work. And why does Jenkins need Credentials, I don't have any Login in Tortoise:
[image]

And if I run that, I get this error:

```
ERROR: Failed to check out file:///C:/Users/a.simon/SVN/MyRepository
svn: E180001: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
svn: E180001: Unable to open repository 'file:///C:/Users/a.simon/SVN/MyRepository'
```

[image]

Setup - Tortoise: So this is my SVN-Folder

[image]

MyCannonAttack contains the Project

[image]

And the repository the repository-stuff

[image]

Comment: What version of svn was the repo made in? Jenkins uses a Java svn implementation which might be older. You can upgrade jenkins svn in the plugins section.

Comment: TortoiseSVN 1.9.4, Build 27285 - 64 Bit , 2016/04/24 13:59:58

Comment: I'd say Jenkins wasn't designed to use the file protocol - I've used Jenkins with SvnServer very well over the years. Jenkins forums might help you more here as it uses svnkit to access the repo.

Comment: Ok, I can't update svn plugin, because its the latest release 2.6
I found this guy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24047441/how-to-integrate-tortoisesvn-and-jenkins but I don't understand his answer

Comment: As far as I know, TortoiseSVN is a client, not a server. Hence you're pointing Jenkins to an already checked-out working copy instead of a repository. Either configure Jenkins using the server repo URL, or if that's not possible just copy the files from your local folder in to the job's workspace instead, and run your build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to configure Visual SVN Server and then try it will work.
https://www.visualsvn.com/server

Comment: Hey, thanks, yeah I will try, I also just read that its just an client .... :D you confirm my premonition. I will get back to this answer later :)

Comment: @Perazim it's a server.

Comment: what do you mean, Tortoise is a client, so I need a server ->visual svn server

Comment: @Perazim Yes you need visual svn server and you need to import your existing repository in SVN server.